# matplotlib: change stem plot linewidth

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

i have image containing 4 subplots:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2) 
    axarr[0,1].stem([1,3,-4],linefmt='b-', markerfmt='bs', basefmt='k-')
    plt.show()
```

I want to change the linewidth of one plot (stem plot). Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I don't have access to test right now, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8409110/812786) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but the link is not helpful. The problem is the combination of subplot and stem.

Answer (score 12):

Here is my solution:

```
 markerline, stemlines, baseline = plt.stem(x, y)
 plt.setp(stemlines, 'linewidth', 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The returned stemlines are a matplotlib [LineCollection](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) and you can change their format like so:

```
stem = plt.stem(x,y)
# stem[1] change stemlines
stem[1].set_linewidth(5)
stem[1].set_linestyles("dashed")
```