# Is it possible to do draw plot in matplotlib where all points are linked to the x axis?

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to find a way in matplotlib to draw a lineplot, except that I don't want to draw a line between points. Instead I want to draw a perpendicular line between each of my points and the x axis.

When I do a standard plot, I obtain the following :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.array([0,1,3,2,3,1,4])
plt.plot(data)
plt.xlim([-0.2,6.2])
plt.ylim([-0.2,5])
```

[image]

Instead I want to obtain the following :

[image]

Any ideas how to do this ? 
Thanks

Comment: `plt.bar(range(data.size), data, width=0.1, color='crimson')`

Comment: A stem plot is another option: `plt.stem(data, linefmt='r-', markerfmt='o')`. (To change linewidth: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953201/matplotlib-change-stem-plot-linewidth))

Comment: Thanks, stem plot is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two other options apart from stem and bar chart is the following using `vlines()` and `LineCollection()`

---

**Option 1 -- Using `vlines()`**

```
for x, y in enumerate(data):
    plt.vlines(x=x, ymin=0, ymax=y, color='r')
```

Or in a single line without using loops

```
plt.vlines(x=range(data.size), ymin=0, ymax=data, color='r')
```

---

**Option 2 -- Using `LineCollection()`**

```
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

lines = [[(x, 0), (x, y)] for x, y in enumerate(data)]
linesCol = LineCollection(lines, linewidths=3, color='r')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(linesCol)
plt.scatter(range(len(data)), data, s=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. Though stem plot is perfect for my case, the LineCollection solution seems highly customizable.

Comment: Why a loop for `plt.vlines` and not in one command`plt.vlines(x=range(data.size), ymin=0, ymax=data, color='r')`?

Comment: @JohanC : Thanks for the tip. I will edit your suggestion to the answer.