# Adding Arbitrary points on pandas time series using Dataframe.plot function

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have been trying to plot some time series graphs using the pandas dataframe plot function. I was trying to add markers at some arbitrary points on the plot to show anomalous points. The code I used :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Entropy Values' : MeanValues}, index=DateRange)
df1.plot(linestyle = '-')
```

[image]

I have a list of Dates on which I need to add markers.Such as:

```
Dates = ['15:45:00', '15:50:00', '15:55:00', '16:00:00']
```

I had a look at this link [matplotlib: Set markers for individual points on a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409095/matplotlib-set-markers-for-individual-points-on-a-line). Does DF.plot have a similar functionality?

I really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DataFrame.plot` passes all keyword arguments it does not recognize to the `matplotlib` plotting method. To put markers at a few points in the plot you can use the `markevery` argument. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'B': range(10)}).set_index('A')
df.plot(linestyle='-', markevery=[1, 5, 7, 8], marker='o', markerfacecolor='r')
```

[image: Example plot]

In your case, you would have to do something like

```
df1.plot(linestyle='-', markevery=Dates, marker='o', markerfacecolor='r')
```