# How do I connect the dots of my scatterplot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to connect the plotted data points.

```
plt.plot(us, mu, 'ro', us, ru, 'go')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Add your codes to your question.

Comment: `ro-`, `go-`. See http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=plot#matplotlib.pyplot.plot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib: Set markers for individual points on a line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409095/matplotlib-set-markers-for-individual-points-on-a-line)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [pyplot documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=plot#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) you can try this.

```
# adding dotted line between points
plt.plot(us, mu, 'r:o', us, ru, 'g:o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: There is no need to call the `plot()` command twice; Matplotlib is quite flexible  in its formatting, so calling `plot`() once with `ro:` and `go:` produces the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i applied it.