# How can I add markers on a bar graph in python?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have made a horizontal bar graph, now I need to add markers on the bars. How can I do so?

The code I have so far is shown below:

[image]

```
def plot_comparison(): 
lengths = [11380, 44547, 166616, 184373, 193068, 258004, 369582, 462795, 503099, 581158, 660724, 671812, 918449]

y_pos = np.arange(len(length))
error = np.random.rand(len(length))

plt.barh(y_pos, length, xerr=error, align='center', alpha=0.4)
plt.yticks(y_pos, length)
plt.xlabel('Lengths')
plt.title('Comparison of different cuts')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib: Set markers for individual points on a line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409095/matplotlib-set-markers-for-individual-points-on-a-line)

Comment: I need to place the markers on the bar graph in this case.

Comment: I believe markers are only available for lined graphs

Comment: Is there any way I can represent certain points on the graph? If not in the form of markers.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add a `plot` command, plotting the `y_pos` against the `lengths`. Make sure to specify a maker and set linestyle to `""` (or `"none"`) otherwise the markers will be connected by straight lines.
The following code may be what you're after.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

lengths = [11380, 44547, 166616, 184373, 193068, 258004, 369582, 462795, 503099, 581158, 660724, 671812, 918449]

y_pos = np.arange(len(lengths))
error = np.array(lengths)*0.08

plt.barh(y_pos, lengths, xerr=error, align='center', alpha=0.4)
plt.plot(lengths, y_pos, marker="D", linestyle="", alpha=0.8, color="r")
plt.yticks(y_pos, lengths)
plt.xlabel('Lengths')
plt.title('Comparison of different cuts')
plt.show()
```

[image]