# Make Line plot markers of different color

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to mark certain indices in the line plot. I have referred to the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409095/matplotlib-set-markers-for-individual-points-on-a-line) on stack overflow and written the following:

```
plt.plot(range(len(y)), y, '-bD', markevery=rare_cases, label='%s' % target_var_name)
```

However, this produces the following:
[image]

How can I keep the line plot in blue but make the markers in red ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [documentation of plt.plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html):

```py
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs)
```

The function takes `**kwargs`:

> **kwargsLine2D properties, optional kwargs are used to specify properties like a line label (for auto legends), line-width, antialiasing, marker face color
> [...]
> Here is a list of available Line2D properties:
> [...]

`markeredgecolor`     or **mec**  color
`markeredgewidth`     or **mew**  float
`markerfacecolor`     or **mfc**  color
`markerfacecoloralt`  or **mfcalt**   color

So, you can feed `markerfacecolor` and `markeredgecolor` as keyword arguments:

```py
x = np.random.randint(0,10,5)
y = np.random.randint(0,10,5)
    
plt.plot(x, y, '-bD',  c='blue', mfc='red', mec='k')
```

[image]