# Making a connected scatter plot in python

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a **connected** scatter plot. I was able to make this simple plot, but I want to add a line between the points within each group. I tried the `linestyle` argument (in below code), but this did not connect the dots. How can I add this line?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

colors = {'RMSE':'red', 'MAE':'green', 'R2':'blue'}

grouped = metrics_df.groupby('metric')
for key, group in grouped:
    group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='num_features', y='score', label=key, color=colors[key], linestyle='solid')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: try adding the following line after `group.plot()`:

`plt.plot('num_features', 'score')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
linestyle='-'
```

and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify arguments like :

```
linestyle='--', marker='o'
```

as specified in the first answer of this question [Set markers for individual points on a line in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409095/set-markers-for-individual-points-on-a-line-in-matplotlib)