# Jupyter notebook - Adding the exact values

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a very simple code of displaying an Excel value table as a graph in Jupyter Notebook.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("file name")
plt.plot(df["viscosity"], df['D'])

plt.xlabel('viscosity[]')
plt.ylabel('D [m^2/s]')
plt.title("The diffusion coeffcient as a function of the viscosity ")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

where the output is a simple line.
I want to add on the graph the exact values ​​in the form of dots. (add on not to replace).

Comment: I've removed your last sentence, as it was another issue. Please create a separate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking how to add `marker` in `plt.plot()`.

Try this -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("file name")
plt.plot(df["viscosity"], df['D'], linestyle='--', marker='o', color='b', label='line with marker'))

plt.xlabel('viscosity[]')
plt.ylabel('D [m^2/s]')
plt.title("The diffusion coeffcient as a function of the viscosity ")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

If the above does not work, you can [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409095/set-markers-for-individual-points-on-a-line-in-matplotlib)